# integer and boolean incompatible types

Tags: while-loop, integer, boolean

this program says the first valid is invalid, no matter what and then the second input is valid no matter what. any idea why?

```
public class test
    {
    public static void main (String [] args)
            {
            int gradeValidity, verifiedGrade, grade, validGrade;


            grade=gradeValidity ();

            System.out.println("your total grade is"+grade);
            System.exit(0);
            }
            private static int gradeValidity ()
            {
            int gradeOne;
            boolean verifiedGrade ;

            gradeOne=ConsoleInput.readInt("Input student grade");
            verifiedGrade=((gradeOne>=0) && (gradeOne<=100));

                            do
                            {
                            System.out.println("Invalid input");
                            gradeOne=ConsoleInput.readInt("Input student grade");
                            }
                            while (!verifiedGrade);



                            return gradeOne;
                            }

            }
```

updated it to this. but now I can incomparable (boolean and int)

```
import io.*;
public class test
    {
    public static void main (String [] args)
            {
            int gradeValidity, verifiedGrade, grade, validGrade;


            grade=gradeValidity ();

            System.out.println("your total grade is"+grade);
            System.exit(0);
            }
            private static int gradeValidity ()
            {
            int gradeOne;
            boolean verifiedGrade ;

            gradeOne=ConsoleInput.readInt("Input student grade");
            verifiedGrade=((gradeOne>=0) && (gradeOne<=100));

                            while (gradeOne!=verifiedGrade);
                            {
                            System.out.println("Invalid input");
                            gradeOne=ConsoleInput.readInt("Input student grade");
                            }




                            return gradeOne;
                            }

            }
```

Its still coming up with errors with this, the first input is always false, the second is always true, regardless of >0 and <100

```
import io.*;
public class test
    {
    public static void main (String [] args)
            {
            int gradeValidity, verifiedGrade, grade, validGrade;


            grade=gradeValidity ();

            System.out.println("your total grade is"+grade);
            System.exit(0);
            }
            private static int gradeValidity ()
            {
            int gradeOne;
            boolean  verifiedGrade;

            gradeOne=ConsoleInput.readInt("Input student grade");
            verifiedGrade=((gradeOne>=0) && (gradeOne<=100));

                            while (!verifiedGrade);
                            {
                                    System.out.println("Invalid input");
                                    gradeOne=ConsoleInput.readInt("Input student grade");
                                    verifiedGrade=((gradeOne>=0) && (gradeOne<=100));
                             }
                            return gradeOne;
                            }

            }
```

Comment: Hi, looks like you're new to StackOverflow -- welcome! Just a note: while it's pretty easy to guess that you're probably using Java, you should, as a general rule, mention what language you're using for this sort of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method gradeValidity should be like this:

```
private static int gradeValidity ()
{
    int gradeOne;
    boolean verifiedGrade;

    gradeOne=ConsoleInput.readInt("Input student grade");
    verifiedGrade=((gradeOne>=0) && (gradeOne<=100));

    while (!verifiedGrade)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        gradeOne=ConsoleInput.readInt("Input student grade");
        verifiedGrade=((gradeOne>=0) && (gradeOne<=100));
    }

    return gradeOne;
}
```

EDIT: Also try this code snippet below. In it I replaced non-standart class ConsoleInput with more standart classes. Tested and it works.

```
private static int gradeValidity () throws java.io.IOException
{
    int gradeOne;
    boolean verifiedGrade;
BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Input student grade");
    gradeOne=Integer.parseInt(bufferRead.readLine());
    verifiedGrade=((gradeOne>=0) && (gradeOne<=100));

    while (!verifiedGrade)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        System.out.println("Input student grade");
        gradeOne=Integer.parseInt(bufferRead.readLine());
        verifiedGrade=((gradeOne>=0) && (gradeOne<=100));
    }

    return gradeOne;
}
```

Comment: When I run that it makes any input false for the first entry and then any input on the second entry is true. Any idea why?

Comment: You are using non-standard class ConsoleInput, there may be bug in it.

Comment: my bad, I had a ";" after "while (!verifiedGrade) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

the line that causes this particular error is this

```
  boolean verifiedGrade;
```

you need to change this line to the following

```
  int verifiedGrade;
```

and everything would work fine Off course until you do not have any other errors!

Answer (score 0):

```
                while (gradeOne=!verifiedGrade)
```

should be

```
                while (gradeOne!=verifiedGrade)
```